# Why does my full screen animation turn the screen black only on the iPad Air?

Tags: ios, arm64

I'm working on a comic book reader that displays full screen images (comic book pages), and animates between them. On the iPad Air, and only the iPad Air, the animation stops and the screen turns black.

The OS seems to think that the screen is showing an image, since taking a screenshot with the hardware buttons takes a picture of the image appropriately. Also, pressing the volume button shows the image again underneath the volume display. Finally, the right screenshot is shown in the dock. But it's still a black screen!

---

**Edit 2014-02-27**

Working with Apple support we've confirmed that this was caused by a bug on their side, likely in UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on iPad Air only with an animation of a big Image.

I fixed it by turning on rasterization during the animation.

```
model.layer.shouldRasterize = YES
model.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Answer (score 0):

The iPad Air uses a 64 bit architecture. Rebuilding the app with arm64 support fixed this issue.

This may have been an issue with my particular code — but if you find yourself having trouble with the iPad Air only (in the iPad family, at least), this could be a good thing to check.

Comment: Sounds like you just masked a bug in your code by compiling for 64-bit.

Comment: In what way do the symptoms lead you to that conclusion?